# Posicionar uma seção do layout abaixo de um header FIXED

Tags: css, posicionamento

-> Eu tenho um layout cujo header é fixo no topo.

-> Só que a section logo abaixo fica em baixo dele e não segue o mesmo fluxo(normal)

Nesse caso qual a melhor forma de fazer a section abaixo ficar abaixo do header?

1) Usando position:relative top:px até a section sair de baixo do header?

2) Colocando uma div vazia com a mesma altura do header antes da section?

Comment: Se ambas as soluções funcionam, não tem uma melhor. Mas não entendi bem a primeira opção, o `top` não deveria ser positivo?

Comment: Sim, viajem, é o costume de usar mais negativo

Comment: @bfavaretto, resalva: O ideal é usar margin-top e não position + coordenada pois a posição deve influir no tamanho da section pós header. Senão tudo oq vem depois da primeira section vai ter q ser posicionado tb.

Comment: É verdade. Por que você não aproveita e posta isso como resposta? ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto boa ideia :)

Answer (score 3):

Normalmente uso o `padding-top` na tag `body` com a mesma altura do elemento, que no caso é, `div.header`.

Ex.:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.header{
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Cabeçalho
</div>
<section>
  <h1>Conteúdo</h1>
</section>
```

Veja este exemplo http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: Colocar padding-top é a melhor opção realmente ou então usar o margin-top na primeira `section`

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é usar `margin-top` e não `position + coordenada` pois a posição deve influir no tamanho da `section` pós header. Senão tudo o que vem depois da primeira `section` (pós-header) também vai ter que ser posicionado também.